# Accessing HTTPonly cookies in PHP

Tags: php, cookies, httponly, cookie-httponly

So, I've been making some custom session initiation code and have run across some issues in uisng HTTPonly cookies, for some reason I am not able to acess the cookies set to HTTPonly using `$_COOKIE["cookie"]`

I've been using the following code to set the cookie and I cannot see the cookie in the dev tools either so I'm unable to understand wether I've made a mistake in making the cookies or is there another way to access the cookies

```
setcookie("cookie","true",time() + (60*60*24*3), "/", true, true)
```

I've tried storing the cookie normally with

```
setcookie("cookie","true",time() + (60*60*24*3), "/", false, false)
```

In this case, I can see the cookie on the dev tool and also can access the cookie within php but as soon as I set HTTPonly to true, the code starts failing.

I have tried fetching with credentials and even tried encoding the cookie in the header but none of those worked. I have gone through the solutions posted but none of them deal with accessing these cookies

Comment: You cant access it from the frontend if that's what you are trying, i don't know what dev tools you are talking about, but if its some frontend dev tools you wont see it. You simply need to check on the network tab that your cookie is sent to the server

Comment: And also, when you put secure to true, you need to be using https, that cookie will not be sent over http. If you only want HttpOnly but not Secure, you should do something like : `setcookie("cookie","true",time() + (60*60*24*3), "/", false, true)`. Also note that when using secure, the cookie will be sent to the client even on http, that's the client that will not sent it back on http. So if you need a secure cookie, be sure to check for https before sending it to the client.

Comment: I'm being able to send an HTTPonly cookie to the client, I need to retrieve the HTTPonly cookie when reconnecting with the client to initialise the session. To initialise the session, I need to be able to verify the cookie value

Comment: You can retrieve the cookie with HttpOnly,  it just prevent the js from accessing it. If it does not work, the most likely scenario is that you enabled Secure and you are on http. Try setting Secure to false.

Comment: could you provide a code snipped to show how to access HTTPonly cookies in PHP?

Comment: it does not change anything to cookie access, it's just prevent access from javascript, you access HttpOnly cookie the same way you access non-HttpOnly cookie using $_COOKIE